# Why the path is getting changed

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I have code which retrieves a direcotry path in 2 different forms. If, in one form, I select a path to open a file and process it, when returning to the other form I am getting a Direcotry Exception error. I used to different strings to get that path

In the second form I called this:

```
       string strFilePath2;
       strFilePath2 = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
       strFilePath2 = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath2).ToString();
       strFilePath2 = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath2).ToString();
       strFilePath2 = strFilePath2 + "\\ACH";
```

In my first form I called:

```
       strFilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
       strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
       strFilePath = Directory.GetParent(strFilePath).ToString();
       strFilePath = strFilePath + "\\ACH\\" + Node;
```

During debugging, I am getting the selected path from the second form, but not the path I expected.  Can any one tell why?

Comment: Please put the exception in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you check the value of the current directory?

The `OpenFileDialog` usually will change the current directory. You can control that behavior using the [`RestoreDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.restoredirectory.aspx) property:

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

ofd.RestoreDirectory = true ; // this will not modify the current directory
```

As an aside, you are concatenating paths in your code sample. In .NET this is best done using the static `Path.Combine` method. This method will check for the presence of a backslash (or whatever the system's path separator character is) and automatically insert one if it is missing:

```
strFilePath = Path.Combine(strFilePath, "ACH");
```

Answer (score 3):

Often this depends on a call of a `FolderBrowserDialog`, a `OpenFileDialog` or something alike. These dialogs (and other components) automatically change the working directory of your  running application.

My advice is to avoid using relative pathes if there is any kind of user interaction.

Comment: I am using Openfiledialog can you suggest how to over come this.

Answer (score 3):

`OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` change the current working path, which is very annoying. You can either reset this manually, or set `.RestoreDirectory = true;` to get it to change back after selecting the file. If you are using `FolderBrowserDialog` you'll have to do it manually if you still get this issue.